# R universal kriging with autoKrige()

Tags: r, spatial, kriging, automap

I'm trying to use the autoKrige() function in the automap package for a simple application of universal kriging. I have an irregularly spaced grid of measurements, and I want to interpolate between them on a fine spatial scale. Example code:

```
    library('automap')

    # create an irregularly spaced grid
    y <-x <-c(-5,-4,-2,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,2,4,5)
    grid <-expand.grid(x,y)
    names(grid) <-c('x', 'y')

    # create some measurements, greatest in the centre, with some noise
    vals <-apply(grid,1, function(x) {12/(0.1+sqrt(x[1]^2 + x[2]^2))+rnorm(1,2,1.5)})

    # get data into sp format
    s <-SpatialPointsDataFrame(grid, data.frame(vals))

    # make some prediction locations and get them into sp format
    pred <-expand.grid(seq(-5,5,by=0.5), seq(-5,5,by=0.5))
    pred <-cbind(pred[,1], pred[,2])    # this seems to be needed, not sure why
    pred <-SpatialPoints(pred)

    # try universal kriging
    surf <-autoKrige(vals~x+y, s, new_data=pred)
```

This results in the error:

```
    Error in gstat.formula.predict(d$formula, newdata, na.action = na.action,  : 
      NROW(locs) != NROW(X): this should not occur
```

I have tried making new_data have the same number of rows as the original data, and have even tried making the co-ordinates in new_data exactly the same as the original data, but I still get this error. I'm new to geostatistics techniques so apologies if I'm making a basic mistake. Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The `pred <-cbind(pred[,1], pred[,2]) ` step can be left out for me, `autoKrige` works even without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have the syntax of the `autoKrige` function wrong. The formula input to `autoKrige` specifies the linear model you want to use, e.g.:

```
log(zinc) ~ dist
```

from the `meuse` dataset. In this case, you model `log(zinc)` versus `dist` using a linear model, and the residuals to this model are interpolated using the variogram. Essentially, universal kriging is linear regression with spatially correlated residuals.

In your case, you specify:

```
val ~ x+y
```

so autoKrige (`gstat` actually) will try to first model the linear model of `vals` versus `x` and `y` (multivariate regression), and interpolate the residuals using the variogram model. However, the `x` and `y` variables are not present in the `SpatialPointsDataFrame`.

What I think you want to do is to only interpolate spatially using the variogram model. In that case, the linear model is very simple, actually just fitting a mean value:

```
vals ~ 1
```

where the mean of `vals` is determined and the residuals are interpolated using the variogram model. This is actually known as Ordinary Kriging. Your call to `autoKrige` would be something like:

```
surf <-autoKrige(vals ~ 1, s, new_data=pred)
```